# How do I get the contents of a JSON file with JSON inside of the array

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I would like some help getting the contents of the JSON file, as the "games" array has JSON inside of it.

Here's the JSON file.

```json
  "games": [
    {
      "creatorId": 3642592,
      "creatorName": "Schwifty Studios",
      "creatorType": "Group",
      "totalUpVotes": 1263723,
      "totalDownVotes": 273834,
      "universeId": 498490399,
      "name": "Mad City",
      "placeId": 1224212277,
      "playerCount": 8386,
      "imageToken": "T_1224212277_e312",
      "isSponsored": false,
      "nativeAdData": "",
      "isShowSponsoredLabel": false,
      "price": null,
      "analyticsIdentifier": null,
      "gameDescription": null
    },
    {
      "creatorId": 708786490,
      "creatorName": "lord_faker08",
      "creatorType": "User",
      "totalUpVotes": 454,
      "totalDownVotes": 1661,
      "universeId": 1274534437,
      "name": "Mad City Mad City Mad City Mad City Mad City Mad C",
      "placeId": 3646141738,
      "playerCount": 5,
      "imageToken": "T_3646141738_ffb3",
      "isSponsored": false,
      "nativeAdData": "",
      "isShowSponsoredLabel": false,
      "price": null,
      "analyticsIdentifier": null,
      "gameDescription": null
    }
  ]
```

I actually tried to get the contents using the number so I could get the data,

```js
games.1.name
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: How about `games[1].name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `games[1].name`. It's the common syntax of accessing object x in an array.

With `games.1.name` you are basically telling the compiler to access the `games` variable, get the `1` property of the object and get the `name` property of the `games.1` object.